# GtkFileChooserDialog in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gtk

I justa want to know if there's a class like GtkFileChooserDialog in Cocoa. This class is used in gtk for opening a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, NSOpenPanel.

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
int result = [panel runModal];
if (result == NSOKButton) {
    NSArray *allSelectedFiles = [panel URLs];
    NSURL *selectedFileURL = [allSelectedFiles objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Selected: %@", selectedFileURL);
}
```

[NSOpenPanel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thx! I tried looking for NSFileChooser, NSDialog and nothing came up.